# What happens when I reach the daily reputation limit?

Tags: support, reputation

What happens if I reach 200 reputation gained in a day. Does it prevent me from getting reputation from accepted answers, votes, bounties etc. or does it move to another day and then I get the reputation delayed on a different day? I would not like to lose unnecessarily from reaching the daily limit. What exactly happens then?

Answer (score 4):

From [What is the daily reputation cap and how can I hit it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32160/what-is-the-daily-reputation-cap-and-how-can-i-hit-it)

> The maximum amount of reputation you can earn in one day from up-votes and approved suggested edits is 200. Any reputation you receive beyond that no longer awards any points [for that day, nor are those points deferred to another day].
>
> You can still earn rep by winning a bounty, accepting an answer, or having one of your answers accepted, and downvotes will still count against you.